# SQL group by two columns where order doesn't matter

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by

Suppose I have this table:

```
col1|col2|score
x   |y   |1
y   |x   |2
z   |w   |4
w   |z   |2
```

and I want to group by col1 and col2 in a way where it doesn't matter if the value comes from col1 or col2, so x|y and y|x are grouped together. The aggregating function can be e.g. AVG. So I want to get the result:

```
col1|col2|score
x   |y   |1.5
z   |w   |3
```

or

```
col1|col2|score
x   |y   |1.5
y   |x   |1.5
z   |w   |3
w   |z   |3
```

I know I can group by two columns, but this won't help me here, so how can I do that?
(I am using SQLite3, but I guess the answer would be about the same for any SQL DB)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation.  Many databases support `least()` and `greatest()`, which simplifies this logic to:

```
select least(col1, col2) as col1, greatest(col1, col2) as col2, avg(score) as score
from t
group by least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2)
order by least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2);
```

In databases that don't support these functions, you can use `case` expressions:

- `least(co1, col2)` --> `(case when col1 < col2 then col1 else col2 end)`
- `greatest(co1, col2)` --> `(case when col1 < col2 then col2 else col1 end)`

In SQLite you can use `min()` and `max()` with more than one argument as equivalents to `least()` and `greatest()`.

Comment: Thanks! Used min() and max() in SQLite3 and it worked fine.